# I'm not understanding combinations and counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question:
An urn has 10 black balls numbered from 1 to 10, and 10 white balls numbered from 1 to 10. In how many ways can we choose 5 balls from the urn?

(There are more questions, which is why there's balls that are different colors and numbered. This is just one of the)

I did answer ${20 \choose 5}$ which is the correct answer. But I don't know *why*, other than the word **choose** being in the question.

Intuitively, I don't understand why $20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 16 \times 17$ isn't an answer for this question. I know it's incorrect and that they're very different answers, but I don't know why. My thinking is that the first ball you choose, you pick out of 20 possible choices, then there's 19, then 18, then 17 choices to pick from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did answer ${20 \choose 5}$ which is the correct answer. But I don't know *why*, other than the word **choose** being in the question.
>
> Intuitively, I don't understand why $20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 16 \times 17$ isn't an answer for this question.

The main reason is that, usually when problems are worded like this, order doesn't matter, i.e. it's a problem about combinations instead of permutations.

Say, if the balls were numbered, I were to pick up balls $\#1-\#5$, in that order. As far as the problem is concerned, this is no different than if I were to pick them up in reverse order. Or, really, any of the $5! = 120$ orderings of the balls. So long as I get those specific balls, the order in which I grab them is unimportant. (Granted the problem could have been worded better to make it clearer. Of course, "choose" and no specifications of order usually are a key sign that order doesn't matter.)

This generalizes for any other group of five balls in that, for any given combination of balls, there are $5!=120$ equivalent ways to have that combination (including the given pairing). Accordingly, your idea of $20 \times \cdots \times 16$ needs to account for this overcounting: it gives us $5!=120$ times more combinations than we want! Luckily, this is easily remedied, and that's why we divide by $5!=120$, and thus the correct answer is given by

$$\binom{20}{5} = \frac{20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16}{5!}$$

This idea leads to the more general formula for this: were there $n$ total balls, and $r$ were drawn, we can get them in

$$\binom n r =  \frac{n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \cdots \times (n-r+2) \times ( n-r+1)}{r!}$$

ways. You might sometimes see alternate notations for the top, sometimes called a "falling factorial." It may be denoted $n^{\underline r}$, or in the iterated product notation by $\prod_{k=1}^r (n-r+k)$. Either way, you basically start at $n$, and then go back by one until you have a total of $r$ numbers, then multiply them all together and divide by $r!$.

Sometimes people are introduced to this briefer, if less intuitive, formula for $\binom n r$. It only takes a little algebra to convince yourself of the equivalence, but you should probably focus on the first for intuition:

$$\binom n r = \frac{n!}{r! \cdot (n-r)!}$$

Answer (score 4):

You've started correctly, thinking 
 $$20×19×18×17×16 $$
picks the five balls one at a time.

Now realize that when you see five of the balls you might have chosen the same five in one of the $5! = 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 120$ possible orders. That means your starting guess counted each possible choice $120$ times. So divide
$$\frac{20×19×18×17×16}{5!} . $$

That's exactly how you compute $\binom{20}{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **choose** $5$ balls from $20$ balls; so the order of the balls does not matter. There are $20×19×18×17×16 $ number of ways contains only  $\frac{20×19×18×17×16 }{5!}$ different *combinations* of the balls. Although,if order of the drawn balls did matter,then yours would be the correct answer.